# DirectX Sprite renders in a different position when scaled

Tags: c++, directx, transformation, directx-9

Currently making some UI classes and UI elements for a game and am coming across an issue when scaling sprites using DirectX 9.

So at the moment I have a `ID3DXSprite*` object (`m_barImage`) which is a health bar.  Obviously as the player health changes, the health bar needs to get longer/shorter.

So I have this in my `Update()` function

```
  // Calculate the width of the bar taking into account the health amount
  float width = (m_maxWidth / 100.0f) * m_percentageFull;

  // compare last width with m_currentWidth to get a scaling ratio
  float resizeRatio = width / m_currentWidth;
  m_currentWidth = width;

  Matrix scaleMatrix;
  D3DXMatrixScaling(&scaleMatrix, resizeRatio, 1.0f, 1.0f);
  m_barImage->SetTransform(&scaleMatrix);
```

and in my `Render()` function I have

```
  m_barImage->Begin(NULL);

  m_barImage->Draw(m_texture, NULL, NULL, &m_position, 0x007F17);

  m_barImage->End();
```

My problem is, as I scale the sprite down in size in the X axis, the position at which the sprite is rended moves to the left.

**NOTE: `m_position` is the position of the sprite set in the constructor and is does NOT change**

Something when scaling the sprite is changing the position at which it is rendered.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read a bit more about the basics of matrix transformations.

With setting the transformation matrix, you're scaling the whole coordinate space and so your position is affected by the scaling too, which leads to the unwanted movement. You should leave the position at the draw-call free and transform your sprite with a translation matrix (move it to the right position) multiplied with the scaling matrix (adjust size). So the size is adjusted before the sprite will be moved around, so the scaling will not applied to the translation.

For more detailed information about transformations, have a look at the following [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. I thought The scaling matrix scaled the local space of the sprite, where as the draw call drew the centre of the sprite at the position in the  world space

Comment: I didn't find a hint in the documentation, but I think the position you pass in the draw step, will be applied before your transformations are applied. Did you try to translate and scale it with the matrix?